# How can I Access ASP.Net Wizard Finish Button in Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net wizard control with the "finish" button defined in the `FinishNavigationTemplate`. I would like to access that button in code to give it focus if finishing the wizard does not complete.

I've tried doing a FindControl on the WizardStep like so:

```
Button b = (Button) wsReviewOrder.FindControl("FinishButton");
```

I've tried doing a FindControl on the entire Wizard control like so:

```
Button b = (Button) wCheckout.FindControl("FinishButton");
```

Neither of these worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran across this post which helped me get the answer:

http://forums.asp.net/t/903710.aspx

This is what worked for me:

```
Button b = (Button)wCheckout.FindControl("FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("FinishButton");
```

Comment: With FinishNavigationTemplateContainerID being the control-generated default ID for the finish navigation container, in case you were wondering.